# Visual Studio Online - Limit access to certain files in project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to limit permission to edit certain files in a project for certain members in my team? Lets say I have a file called "index.html", that file cannot be edited by "User X", etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the project uses classic TFVC, the answer is yes. The trick is to set proper permission at the file level.

Navigate to the file on the web interface, on the left tree, there is a small down triangle that opens the context menu, select Security and there you go.